# Plotting multiple ROC curves

Tags: matlab

I need to vary a parameter in my experiments, and save the `X,Y` from `perfcurve` in each run. Unfortunately, they are a different size each time.

```
for ii=1:length(myparams)
    %some previous calculations
    [X,Y,T,abc] = perfcurve(true, scores, 1);
    X_all(ii, :) = X;
    Y_all(ii, :) = Y;
end
Plot(X_all, Y_all)
```

I'd like to get this working, but I can't figure out how to save the `X`and `Y` each time through the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving vectors of unequal length is easily implemented by a [cell array](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html).

Here the adaption of your problem:

```
X_all = cell([1 length(myparams)]);
Y_all = cell([1 length(myparams)]);

for ii=1:length(myparams)
    %some previous calculations
    [X,Y,T,abc] = perfcurve(true, scores, 1);
    X_all{ii} = X;
    Y_all{ii} = Y;
end

figure, hold on
for ii=1:length(myparams)
    plot(X_all{ii}, Y_all{ii});
end
```